# Visual Studio Code trigger hot deployment via script

Tags: linux, macos, flutter, visual-studio-code, scripting

I am developing an app using Flutter, and I want to be able to test some functionality that behaves slightly different depending on the device directly on both an iPhone and an Android device.

I am using a Linux machine with Visual Studio Code as my main development machine (and do not want to change that), and on that machine Visual Studio Code is deploying to an Android emulator (or a real device).

Then I have a Mac, which has also got Visual Studio Code installed. I mounted the "lib" directory from the Linux machine via sshfs to the Mac (the rest of the Flutter project is just copied to there, since for example I do not want to share the build-folder). From there Visual Studio Code deploys the app to either the simulator or a real iPhone.

With this setup, whenever I change a file, Visual Studio Code on the Linux maching deploys directly to Android. However, since file system events do not get picked up on the Mac due to sshfs, Visual Studio Code on the Mac does not directly deploy. I only have to trigger a hot deployment though (which I mapped to F5), so even now it is only one keypress I have to do on the Mac.

My question is, can I somehow automate this last step? I was thinking about using ssh to connect from the Mac to Linux, and then pick up the filesystem events via inotify. But how could I then trigger a hot deployment on the Mac?